# Parse requests.get() output into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I am following a tutorial an am stuck at parsing the output of requests.get()

My goal is to connect to the API below to pull historical crypto-currency prices and put them into a pandas dataframe for further analysis.

[API: https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#-api-data-histoday-]

Here's what I have.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histodayfsym=ETC&tsym=USD&limit=10&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG") 



print(response.text)
```

Now I want to output into a dataframe...

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response)
```

But I get...
PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: `response` isn't a dictionary - maybe `.from_dict(response.json())`?

Comment: That gets me a bit closer! Now it is in a df, but the keys and values are all out of order... I need the timestamp to be in a datetime format I think then call the the index

Answer (score 6):

You can use the json package to convert to dict:

```
import requests
from json import loads
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histodayfsym=ETC&tsym=USD&limit=10&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG") 

dic = loads(response.text)

print(type(dic))

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)
```

However as jonrsharpe noted, a much more simple way would be:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histodayfsym=ETC&tsym=USD&limit=10&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG") 


print(type(response.json()))
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response.json())
```

Comment: You actually do not: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Comment: Indeed, i stand corrected :), i have update answer to reflect this